# input field and convert to pdf

Tags: java, android, perl

i would like to know if anyone would have the answer for this sequence.

on my android interface, i have 5 spinners that gather user inputs and then click send button that will send these inputs to a specific server. the server will receive these inputs and replace them into a template pdf to replace the blank fields on the pdf document. following that, the server will send back the completed pdf to the user's email id as an attachment.

does anyone know how to script these sequences? much help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Flying Saucer](http://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/) to create PDF files.
Flying Saucer takes XML or XHTML and applies CSS 2.1-compliant stylesheets to it, in order to render to PDF (via iText), images, and on-screen using Swing or SWT. The library implements (basically) the entirety of CSS 2.1 and aims to be fully compliant with the W3C specification; it includes a small handful of CSS 3 features.